# Project Help-unable to pass value through function

Tags: c, pointers

I have a project for school i'm currently working on. We have to divide two numbers and display the answer along with the remainder. The value is correct within the function, but when i'm trying to pass it through main, it gives me the wrong number. Thanks for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
void division (int number, int divisor, int *quotient, int *remainder);
int main(void)
{
    int i, d, q, r;
    int *quotient = &q;
    int *remainder = &r;
    printf("Enter an integer and divisor, separated by comma: ");
    scanf("%d, %d", &i, &d);

    division(i, d, quotient, remainder);

    printf("%d divided by %d: quotient = %d, remainder = %d\n", i, d, 
        *quotient, *remainder);
    return 0;
}

void division(int number, int divisor, int *quotient, int *remainder)
{
    int a = number / divisor;
    printf(" a = %d\n", a);
    int b = number % divisor;
    printf(" b = %d\n", b);
    quotient = *a;
    remainder = *b;
}
```

Comment: `quotient = *a;
remainder = *b;` --> `*quotient = a;
*remainder = b;`

Comment: The code doesn't compile — or shouldn't compile.  `*a` is invalid since `a` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values in correctly in division function.
try 
*quotient = a;
*remainder = b;
You are doing a pass by reference, so you need to assign the values to quotient and remainder.